# Ubuntu server problem with FollowSymlinks

Tags: server, apache2, php

The server is from company named contabo if that makes any difference
Ubuntu 20.04+lamp installed
I have a PHP script and for some reason if I try to navigate on the backend all links are 404 (The requested URL was not found on this server.)

One source suggested to go to /etc/apache2/sites-available/
and edit a file which sits there by default so in my case it is "000-default.conf"
add the code

```
  <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
```

then run

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

However this did not helped me as I still get 404 page error.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the source code for the website? Is it in `/var/www/html` or somewhere else? Do you have the PHP modules enabled? Do you use `.htaccess` rewrites? A little more info is needed here.

Comment: my bad, I haven't copied .htaccess file to the root directory of the script.